# ROS and Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could ROS work under Ubuntu 10.10?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9058/ros-and-ubuntu-10.10/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most definitely.

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu for instructions on how to install ROS on Ubuntu, including Ubuntu 10.10.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-02-14**:
i see... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look at the [target platform REP document](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html), which describes which ROS releases will be compatible with which Ubuntu platforms.   10.10 is supported for C Turtle, Diamondback, and Electric.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-02-15**:
ok! Thanks!